# How can I use Spring Cloud OpenFeign with Spring Boot 3.0.0-M4?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I want to use Spring Cloud OpenFeign with Spring Boot 3.0.0-M4 But I could not find the compatible version of Spring Cloud OpenFeign with spring boot 3.0.0-M4.
for using OpenFeign with this version of spring boot what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Spring Boot milestone version `3.0.0-M5` got released end of September.
You can use the corresponding Spring Cloud version `2022.0.0-M5` which includes Spring Cloud Openfeign  4.0.0-M5.
See https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/06/spring-cloud-2022-0-0-m5-is-now-available

(The same most probably works with M4 if you really have to use it)

However I would advise on using https://start.spring.io to generate your project stub and maven or gradle files that take care of selecting the correct versions for Spring Cloud modules like Openfeign.

Shortened example for `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0-M5'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
  set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.0-M5")
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
  }
}
```